# Advanced search query to find single letter file extension in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I am trying to search for all files in Windows 7 with extension ".p" and I do not want ".pdf" or ".pd". As of now, I am using "ext:p" and every file with extension p including pdf are being displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap what you want to search for in quotations so that Windows knows you mean a literal string.

`ext:"p"`

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response. Happy Friday to you!